# Android watchdog sent SIGKILL to system_server, but why did the log say "Fatal signal 6"?

Tags: android, sigabrt, watchdog, sigkill

In the log, Watchdog killed system_server by sending `SIGKILL`, but how did the log say "`Fatal signal 6` (`SIGABRT`)"?
I know that a process terminates after receiving `SIGKILL`, why did it receive `SIGABRT` then?
Can anyone explain it to me? Many thanks.

### The following are some logs:

```
7703 02-20 20:50:56.290 25333 25492 W Watchdog: No process is given for creating tombstones on framework reboot.
 7704 02-20 20:50:56.290 25333 25492 W Watchdog: *** WATCHDOG KILLING SYSTEM PROCESS: com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService



7617 02-20 20:50:52.290 25333 25333 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000062f5 (code=0)
 7618 02-20 20:50:54.380 25284 25284 I DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
 7619 02-20 20:50:54.380 25284 25284 I DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/mione_plus/mione_plus:4.0.4/IMM76D/3.2.1:user/release-keys'
 7620 02-20 20:50:54.380 25284 25284 I DEBUG   : pid: 25333, tid: 25333  >>> system_server <<<
 7621 02-20 20:50:54.380 25284 25284 I DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code 0 (?), fault addr --------
 7622 02-20 20:50:54.380 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :  r0 00ce0ca0  r1 00000080  r2 00000002  r3 00000000
 7623 02-20 20:50:54.380 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :  r4 00ce0ca0  r5 00000000  r6 00000002  r7 000000f0
 7624 02-20 20:50:54.380 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :  r8 00000000  r9 00ce0ca0  10 00000000  fp 00000001
 7625 02-20 20:50:54.380 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :  ip 00000002  sp bebfc218  lr 400ab5b0  pc 400a66ec  cpsr 60000010
 7626 02-20 20:50:54.380 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :  d0  002e006d006f0063  d1  00720064006e0061
 7627 02-20 20:50:54.380 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :  d2  002e00640069006f  d3  0065006c00610063
 7628 02-20 20:50:54.380 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :  d4  002e006d006f0063  d5  00720064006e0061
 7629 02-20 20:50:54.380 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :  d6  002e00640069006f  d7  0076006f00720070
 7630 02-20 20:50:54.390 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
 7631 02-20 20:50:54.390 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
 7632 02-20 20:50:54.390 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
 7633 02-20 20:50:54.390 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
 7634 02-20 20:50:54.390 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :  d16 00000006427e8300  d17 006e0061004d0079
 7635 02-20 20:50:54.390 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :  d18 0064006e0065006c  d19 0000000000720061
 7636 02-20 20:50:54.390 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :  d20 0000000100000000  d21 0000001400000001
 7637 02-20 20:50:54.390 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :  d22 002e006d006f0063  d23 00720064006e0061
 7638 02-20 20:50:54.390 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :  d24 4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c  d25 4545454545454545
 7639 02-20 20:50:54.390 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :  d26 2020202020202020  d27 4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c
 7640 02-20 20:50:54.390 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :  d28 0100010001000100  d29 0100010001000100
 7641 02-20 20:50:54.390 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :  d30 4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c  d31 4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c
 7642 02-20 20:50:54.390 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :  scr 60000012
 7643 02-20 20:50:54.390 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :
 7644 02-20 20:50:54.600 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :          #00  pc 0000d6ec  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3)
 7645 02-20 20:50:54.600 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :          #01  pc 000125ac  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_mutex_lock)
 7646 02-20 20:50:54.600 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :          #02  pc 0005d666  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 7647 02-20 20:50:54.600 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :          #03  pc 0005dea2  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmLockObject)
 7648 02-20 20:50:54.600 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :          #04  pc 0002031c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 7649 02-20 20:50:54.600 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :          #05  pc 00034f48  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z12dvmInterpretP6ThreadPK6MethodP6JValue)
 7650 02-20 20:50:54.600 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :          #06  pc 0006c0d6  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z14dvmCallMethodVP6ThreadPK6MethodP6ObjectbP6JValueSt9__va_list)
 7651 02-20 20:50:54.600 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :          #07  pc 00058cb0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 7652 02-20 20:50:54.600 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :          #08  pc 0004802e  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
 7653 02-20 20:50:54.600 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :          #09  pc 00063656  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
 7654 02-20 20:50:54.610 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :          #10  pc 00018bfc  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android7BBinder8transactEjRKNS_6ParcelEPS1_j)
 7655 02-20 20:50:54.610 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :          #11  pc 0001bf06  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14executeCommandEi)
 7656 02-20 20:50:54.610 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :          #12  pc 0001c0e2  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14joinThreadPoolEb)
 7657 02-20 20:50:54.610 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :          #13  pc 0000136c  /system/lib/libsystem_server.so (system_init)
 7658 02-20 20:50:54.610 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :          #14  pc 0000b30c  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so
 7659 02-20 20:50:54.610 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :          #15  pc 0001fa30  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke)
 7660 02-20 20:50:54.610 25284 25284 I DEBUG   :          #16  pc 0005993e  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z16dvmCallJNIMethodPKjP6JValuePK6MethodP6Thread)
```